# ArrayList of custom objects is overwritten whenever I add to it from another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, arraylist, android-asynctask

I'm trying to pass an article object from one fragment to another fragment via the activity that they share. So far the object is being passed over, but the whenever more than one item in the listview of the ArticlesFragment is selected to be saved, the CollectionsFragment doesn't append to the ArrayList, and simply overwrites it. Leaving only one article to be shown in that fragment.

ArticlesFragment.java

```
package fragments;

/* Imports */

public class ArticlesFragment extends Fragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

    private final String urlString = "https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=reuters&sortBy=top&apiKey=4b240d3be86c4f69856af11e51432cbc";
    private final String progressMsg = "Loading in articles...";

    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipe;
    private List<Article> articleList;
    private ListView lvArticles;
    private ArticleAdapter adapter;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public ArticlesFragment() {
    }

    public static ArticlesFragment newInstance() {
        ArticlesFragment fragment = new ArticlesFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        new JSONTask().execute(urlString);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_articles, container, false);
        swipe = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);
        swipe.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getContext()).build();
        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        new JSONTask().execute(urlString);
        swipe.setRefreshing(false);
    }

    public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, List<Article>> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.setMessage(progressMsg);
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected List<Article> doInBackground(String... params) {
            HttpsURLConnection connection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            try {
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();
                InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                String line = "";
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line);
                }

                String finalJson = buffer.toString();

                JSONObject parent = new JSONObject(finalJson);
                JSONArray parentArray = parent.getJSONArray("articles");

                articleList = new ArrayList<>();

                Gson gson = new Gson();

                for (int i = 0; i < parentArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Article article = gson.fromJson(finalObject.toString(), Article.class);
                    articleList.add(article);
                }

                return articleList;

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
                try {
                    if (reader != null) {
                        reader.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Article> s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            adapter = new ArticleAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.row, s);

            lvArticles = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.lvArticles);
            lvArticles.setAdapter(adapter);

            lvArticles.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Article item = articleList.get(position);
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(getContext(), WebViewActivity.class);
                    intent1.putExtra("URL", item.getUrl());
                    getContext().startActivity(intent1);
                }
            });

            lvArticles.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    // TODO Implement article saves.
                    Article item = articleList.get(position);
                    createDialog(view, item);
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }

        private void createDialog(View view, final Article item) {

            final Dialog d = new Dialog(getContext());
            d.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
            d.setTitle("Add article?");
            d.setCancelable(true);

            Button b = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("Article", item);
                    getContext().startActivity(intent);
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "YES", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            d.show();

        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.fyp.chowdud.dynamo;

/* Imports */

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, new ArticlesFragment())
                    .commit();
        }

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        Fragment fragment = null;

        if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
            fragment = new ArticlesFragment();
        } else {
            fragment = new CollectionsFragment();
            passData(fragment);
        }

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    public void passData(Fragment fragment) {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Article aitem = (Article) intent.getSerializableExtra("Article");
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable("Article", aitem);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    }

}
```

CollectionsFragment.java

```
package fragments;


/* Imports */

public class CollectionsFragment extends Fragment {

    private List<Article> articleList;
    private ListView lvArticles;
    private ArticleAdapter adapter;

    Article v = null;

    public CollectionsFragment() {
    }

    public static CollectionsFragment newInstance() {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        CollectionsFragment fragment = new CollectionsFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_collections, container, false);

        if (articleList == null) {
            new MyTask().execute();
        }

        return view;
    }

    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            Bundle bundle = getArguments();
            v = (Article) bundle.getSerializable("Article");
            articleList = new ArrayList<>();
            articleList.add(v);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            lvArticles = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.lvArticles);
            adapter = new ArticleAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.row, articleList);
            lvArticles.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: That's because you set a new adapter with a new list with only one item in your MyTask onPostExecute.

Comment: I'm not really sure about this...So should I set the adapter outside MyTask?

Comment: Yes, you should set the adapter only once actually. Then you could just create a new method on the adapter and pass the new articles (in MyTask) in there and then append the articles within the adapter, for example.

Comment: Just to clarify, when talking about setting the adapter, do you mean the setAdapter() or mean instantiating the adapter?

Comment: both. As soon as you set a new adapter on a ListView it overwrites the data of the ListView with the new data of the adapter you just set.

Comment: So I should put the listview and adapter in the onCreateView function?